# En un While puedo hacer resultados con información distinta

Tags: php, javascript, html

tengo un ciclo while sacado de una BD, en ellos salen los resutados con dos botones, uno es "Lo quiero" y el otro "Detalles". Se le dan a lo quiero va automaticamente al carrito y si le dan a detalles, se abre un modal con la información. Todo eso lo hace correcto, pero hay uno de ellos que en lugar de que ponga "Lo quiero" quiero que ponga más información y se redirija a otra pagina distinta del carrito. ¿Eso se puede hacer?

```
  <?php
     $id =$_GET['ID'];
     $nece =$_GET['necesito'];
     $result = null;
        if($_GET['necesito'] == 0){
          $results = $mysqli->query("
             SELECT productos.id, productos.producto, productos.imagen, 
             productos.alias, posibles.id AS idPosi, 
             posibles.idproducto, posibles.tipo, posibles.entrada, 
             posibles.mensualidad, posibles.final, 
             posibles.total,posibles.primerPago 
             FROM productos, posibles 
             WHERE productos.id = posibles.idproducto 
             AND posibles.idproducto = $id");
        }else{
            $results = $mysqli->query("
             SELECT productos.id, productos.producto, productos.imagen, 
             productos.alias, posibles.id AS idPosi, 
             posibles.idproducto, posibles.tipo, posibles.entrada, 
             posibles.mensualidad, posibles.final, 
             posibles.total,posibles.primerPago 
             FROM productos, posibles 
             WHERE productos.id = posibles.idproducto 
             AND posibles.idproducto = $id 
             AND posibles.tipo = $nece");
              }
              mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
              while($res = $results->fetch_array()) {
              ?>

        <div class="col-12 planos">
         <div class="row planos2">
           <div class="col-1"><img src="images/maquinas/<?php echo $res['imagen']; ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid"></div>
           <div class="col-2 plan4 corrijepad">
               <h4><?php
                if ($res['tipo'] == 1) echo "Alquiler";
                if ($res['tipo'] == 2) echo "Comprar";
                if ($res['tipo'] == 3) echo "Explotación compartida";
                if ($res['tipo'] == 5) echo "Alq. con opción a compra";
                ?></h4></p>
             <p><?php echo $res['producto']; ?> <span><?php echo $res['alias']; ?></span></p>
              </div>
             <div class="col-2 plan6 center">
               <h4>ENTRADA</h4>
                 <p><?php echo $res['entrada']; ?>€</p>
             </div>
             <div class="col-2 plan6 center" style="padding: 0px;">
               <h4>CUOTA</h4>
                 <p><?php echo $res['mensualidad']; ?><span>€/mes</span></p>
             </div>
             <div class="col-2 plan6 center" style="padding: 0px;">
               <h4>FINAL</h4>
                 <p><?php echo $res['final']; ?>€</p>
             </div>
             <div class="col-2 plan6 center" style="padding: 0px;">
               <h4>TOTAL</h4>
             <div id="pvp"><p style="color: #f67b48;"><?php echo $res['total']; ?>€</p></div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-1 pull-right" style="padding: 0px;">

              <form action="carrito.php" method="post" name="compra">
                <input name="id_txt" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $res['id']; ?>"/>
                <input name="Imagen" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $res['imagen']; ?>"/>
                <input name="Tipo" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $res['tipo']; ?>"/>
                <input name="Producto" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $res['producto']; ?> <?php echo $res['alias']; ?>"/>
                <input name="Entrada" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $res['entrada']; ?>"/>
                <input name="primerPago" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $res['primerPago']; ?>"/>
                <input name="cantidad" type="hidden" value="1"/>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary bonton-quiero ">Lo quiero</button>
           <a data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $res['idPosi']; ?>" href="#modalDetalles" class="btn btn-primary bonton-quiero2 ">Detalles</a>

            </form>
           </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

¿En base a qué quieres hacer esa distinción?

Lo que podrías hacer es poner un if con la condición a partir de la cual puedes distinguir el producto que quieres que muestre diferente información

Comment: Por lo que pongo arriba, es una lista de productos que sale de un wile, pero uno de ellos necesito que su enlace sea diferente ya que tiene que abrir una ventana distinta.

Comment: Pero ¿qué característica en particular tiene el producto para que necesites que aparezca diferente información?

Comment: Sale una lista de productos que se pueden comprar directamente a través de un carrito, y este no se puede comprar, se tiene que solicitar información a través de un formulario

Comment: ¿En la BD hay algún campo en el que se tenga una bandera o algo asi  que marque el producto como que no se puede comprar?

Comment: Hola perdona, pero los días de puente e desconectado @Agares. Eso no seria un problema le puedo añadir un campo sin problema, la cuestión es como generar el contenido como necesito